open-webui serve returns Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
I successfully ran pip install open-webui on a Windows 11 laptop having Python 3.11.0 via PowerShell but I can't seem to run exe files - what do I have to do to run this ? What do I have to tell me admin to enable ?
(env) PS C:\test\open-webui\env\Scripts> open-webui serve
Program 'open-webui.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ open-webui serve
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ open-webui serve
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
 

